# Is it better to have one large VDB or a bunch of small ones?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, smoke-simulation, volumetrics, file-format

While making a cloudscape I was wondering which would be the better way to go about it.

Is better to have 1 large VDB with a bunch of dense spots for clouds but mostly empty space, or an individual VDB for each cloud?